# How to use Spring XD Module Options in SpEL expression of Spring Integration DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-el

I'm implementing a custom Spring XD module (processor).
I've added Module Options to it, they can be easily referenced in `ModuleConfiguration` via `@Value("${varName}")` syntax.

However, I can't use them directly in SpEL expressions of the flow builder:

```
return IntegrationFlows
            .from(input)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h
                    .headerExpression("varHeader", "varName") //That's the line with an issue
            )
            .transform(customTransformer)
            .channel(output)
            .get();
```

Is there a way to use the directly in the flow builder, not injecting into the configuration bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem of Spring XD, neither Spring Integration Java DSL or even just Java & Annotation Configuration.

The difference between Java Config and XML config (in this case), that the properties for XML bean definitions undergo an additions transformation phase - `BeanDefinition` properties merge. It is helpful for the target object creation.

With that you can define your `expression` property with the Property Placeholder value to be extracted before the targeg object creation.

Right, with Java Config we have the `BeanDefinition` as well, but with Java Config the object instantiation is fully in your hands. Therefore any `set...()` is out of Container scope and it can't determine that your value is with Property Placeholder.

The Java & Annotation Configuration suggests to use `@Value("${varName}")` and use the value directly in your `@Bean` method. From other side you even can move that annotation to the method definition:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(@Value("${varName}") String myValue) {
.....
}
```

There is another trick, which won't be so elegant for because it is a bit verbose:

```
.headerExpression("varHeader", "@environment.getProperty('varName')")
```

The `Environment` to resolve Property Placeholders is exposed as a bean and any Spring Integration Expressions have access to bean factory.
Only bottleneck that this Expression  will be evaluated for each message, not once like it is in case of `@Value("${varName}")`.

Comment: Artem, thanks for the clarification! I understand that `headerExpression` will get evaluated for each message, but that's fine in my case, as this particular stream would start with `trigger |`